# Comparing Generic Type Properties in ADO.NET LINQ to Entities Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities

**The Goal**

I'm trying to compare primary keys of two generic types in ADO.NET's LINQ to Entities.  The trick is, I can't explicitly compare the properties in the LINQ query because I'm using generic types.  Thus, I have to dynamically retrieve the value of the property from both objects in order to compare them.

While I can manually loop through each row in the DB on the application side (my current production approach), I'd still prefer to retrieve direct from the DB using LINQ.  It would just keep things simpler I suppose.

**The Problem**

When trying to use a custom helper, or anything that isn't directly related to the entity itself, the LINQ query fails as not being supported.  It is my understanding that when using 'LINQ to Entities', the actual LINQ query is executed using SQL.  Being that as it is, I'm extremely limited on how I can handle the conditionals.

**Disclamer**

**This in NOT me asking how to use methods in a LINQ query.**  Most of the stuff I'm outlining right now will more or less serve for any future visitors who have the same question/issue.
I'm aware that it's not possible to handle this the way I'm attempting.  My question is whether or not there is a creative way to handle LINQ to Entities queries using generic types.  I'm sure the answer will be 'it's not possible', but I'd like to get some more expert knowledge on the topic.  Perhaps somebody who has attempted this before.

**Exception**

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
'Boolean CompareKeys[MyEntityType](System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],
MyApp.DB.MyEntityType, MyApp.DB.MyEntityType)' method, 
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
```

**Action**

```
private static void MergeEntityListToDB<T>(List<T> list)
{
    var primaryKeys = new List<string>() { "MyEntityTypeID" };
    foreach (var row in list)
    {
        T ExistingRecord = dbRows
            .Where(x => CompareKeys(primaryKeys, row, x)).FirstOrDefault();

        // Remaining Logic
    }
}
```

**Helper**

```
private static bool CompareKeys<T>(List<string> PKs, T obj1, T obj2)
{
    foreach (var key in PKs)
    {
        var val1 = obj1.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(obj1, null).ToString();
        var val2 = obj2.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(obj2, null).ToString();
        if (val1 != val2)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `dynamic` in your code? What is the type of `listOfSameType`? What is the type of `dbRows`? What is the `T` at the beginning of the `foreach` body?

Comment: @NetMage Apologies, I meant generic types, not literal 'dynamic' type.  the list in the foreach is of the same type as the rows in the dbset ('dbRows').  The T is the generic type.  The literal type is an Entity Type generated by ADO.NET EF5, DB First.  The explicit type and makeup are irrelevant in this exact scenario.  I've updated the question details in response to your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to combine LINQ Dynamic Query and possibly LINQKit to achieve your goals. EF (and LINQ to SQL) can't translate reflection to SQL to query a database.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Dynamic Query alone was enough to accomplish what I was after so your answer is correct.  Unfortunately, it ended up being faster to manually loop through every single record in memory.  It's not ideal but that's another topic completely.  Thank you again.

Comment: What type of database are you accessing with ADO.Net? Recently when trying to speed up LINQ to a CSV file with either SQLite or SQL Compact Edition, I noticed that my queries still running on the same PC weren't any faster than LINQ to objects/CSV file. Not having a real database server can make going through a LINQ driver slower than direct object querying.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL directly using entity framework.  Sad part is, I'm only working with about 150k rows.  I believe it's because I'm having to take a longer route to get my values on account of them being generic types.  I haven't fully tested this theory yet though.

Comment: If you aren't already, I would consider using LINQPad to run tests and examine the generated SQL to see what might be happening. Generic types are instantiated at compile time in C# and shouldn't be particularly slower than static types, but Reflection is very slow.